# I was given a command 14.04

Tags: command-line

I was given a command that would copy the file from my root and save it to `/var/www/html` and if the original file was modified, it would update the `/var/www/html` version with the modification as it happens.

The command was `ls -s /acnl/data/stats/stats.json /var/www/html/json/stats.json`

It's not working how I want it to. What command would I need to use to do what I need?

Comment: I guess you made a "ln -s /acnl/data/stats/stats.json /var/www/html/json/stats.json" instead of "ls", right ?

Comment: yeah.............................

Comment: And what is your goal ? if you edit or change /acnl/data/stats/stats.json, this changes should also apply to   /var/www/html/json/stats.json ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I entered

```
ls -s /acnl/data/stats/stats.json /var/www/html/json/stats.json
```

instead of

```
ln -s /acnl/data/stats/stats.json /var/www/html/json/stats.json
```

My bad!

Comment: Maybe give some credit to @lkj for pointing that out?